# Qt foreach loop ordering vs. for loop for QList

Tags: c++, qt, for-loop, foreach, qt4

When iterating through a `QList<T>` with a `foreach` loop, in the tests I conducted the items are returned in the same order as they are with a standard `for` loop.

My question is, will the `foreach` always return items in numerical order by index like this, for containers that have natural ordering (like `QList` and `QVector`)?  For example, are the following *always* equivalent?

```
QList<T> list;

for( int i=0; i<list.count(); ++i )
{ 
    // process items in numerical order by index
    // do something with "list[i]";
}

foreach( T item, list )
{ 
    // will items always be processed in numerical order by index?
    // do something with "item";
}
```

Comment: You cant use [i] operator on list, but only in table (vectors ...) to have a random acces on memory. Moreover, try the c++11 foreac loop : (for(T& item : list) {/*some code */}). May be this can help

Comment: @Krozark Nope, `operator[]` works just fine. See: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#operator-5b-5d

Comment: @NikosC. Ok, but not in STL. So for your problem, the most efficient is to use iterators  using begin() and end() (i realy don't know what the foreach macro do ...)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `foreach` macro (aka. `Q_FOREACH`) uses the `begin()` and `end()` iterator request methods of the container.

So if your container is a `QList` or `QVector` then your examples will always be equivalent.  You can view the `foreach` source code [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_FOREACH).

The `foreach` macro isn't great though, it makes a copy of the container - so only use on containers that support implicit-sharing.  Use C++11 `for( : ) {}` loops if available, otherwise Boost has an equivalent that is superior.

Comment: Link is dead. Please avoid linking without giving the answer as well (or an extract).

Comment: @cmannett85, can you tell me how to loop QList using `for ( : ) { }` ? sorry for asking 8 years ago question

Comment: @Freedom_Ben, can you tell me how to loop QList using for ( : ) { } ?

Comment: @cmanett85, I've used thousands of foreach loop in my project, and I realized that moving to for (:){} can lead to a great performance upgrade after seeing your answer. please help me. I have snippet.h and copy all iterations from that file, and unfortunately it was foreach version.

Comment: @DenisTurgenev https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for and you won't see a 'great performance upgrade' because `QList` is a Qt container and therefore uses implicit sharing.

Comment: thank you, @cmannett85, so for QList, foreach and for(:){} both don't make a copy of the container ??

Comment: yes, Qt says that "Since Qt 5.7, the use of this macro is discouraged. It will be removed in a future version of Qt. Please use C++11 range-for, possibly with qAsConst(), as needed." And maybe `for ( :) {}` seems to be a better practice.

Just surprising, how compiler can detect container classes(even Qt Class). It's awesome

Comment: How do I know if the container support implicit sharing?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information found [here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2009/01/23/iterating-efficiently/), `foreach` is much slower than the first, suggesting that it is not equivalent.

Comment: You are right, but you haven't understood why.  In those tests the *first* `foreach` test was so much slower because of the creation of a `QString` shallow copy on each iteration, using a const ref of the actual container data made the times go back to roughly the same as the other tests because it bypassed the shallow copy.  Conversely using a list of `ints` would have had the same effect.