# What is wrong with foreach in Qt?

Tags: qt

Well, I tried it all. This should be very simple, yet I am stock at finding out what in the world is going on with my foreach. It just don't help.

```
    #include <QCoreApplication> 
    //coreapplication or Qapplication the error is there
    #include <QList>
    #include <QDebug>

    int main()
    {
      QList<int> list;

      list << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4 << 5;

      foreach (int i, list) //expected token ';' got 'int'.
      {
        qDebug() << i;
      }
    }
    /*
    QT += core gui

    TARGET = QtTest
    CONFIG += console
    CONFIG -= app_bundle
    CONFIG += no_keywords

    TEMPLATE = app

    SOURCES += main.cpp

    */
```

Comment: It works fine in my case, Qt 5.2. What is your qt version? Also have you tried C++11's for each syntax?

Comment: 5.5.1.... I looked on the website as in the qt assistant, O_o same thing...

Comment: Maybe `foreach` is disabled for your setup. Try `Q_FOREACH` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You specified `no_keywords` in your config.  You have to use `Q_FOREACH` instead of `foreach`.  See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#foreach) for `foreach`.

That being said, I would switch to the C++11 range-based `for`, since it doesn't have issues with commas in types.  For example,

```
Q_FOREACH (QPair<int, int> p, pairList)
```

won't compile since the preprocessor thinks you're trying to invoke the macro with 3 arguments instead of 2.

Comment: One can work around the comma issue with a typedef, but yes, range-based for is to be preferred if one can use it.

Comment: Interestingly enough im getting the same error but I have the correct project configuration. Not only that, foreach works on Qt containers but not an array containing a primitive type like int

Answer (score 4):

Instead you can use the [C++11 `for(:)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for(int i:list)
{
    qDebug() << i;
}
```

Note that you will have to compile with the `C++-11` flag, therefore add this line to your project file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Note that the C++11 `for` is more efficient than the Qt `foreach` as indicated by: [Qt foreach loop ordering vs. for loop for QList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825376/qt-foreach-loop-ordering-vs-for-loop-for-qlist)

**Edit:**
Like commented by Frank Osterfeld you can also use:

```
CONFIG+=c++11
```

in your `.pro` file since Qt 5.4 as commented here: [How to use C++11 in your Qt Projects.](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_use_C%2B%2B11_in_your_Qt_Projects)

Comment: Yea, that one seems to not work either, it gave me an error: range-base 'for' loops are not allowed in C++ 98 mode.

Comment: nvm.. I missed that one step.... yea it works, but still... I wanted to practice with foreach and is a surprise it wont work in my machine.

Comment: I’d use CONFIG+=c++11 instead of "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11"