# How to remove `fromStdVector` method from Qt 6.3.0 c++ code

Tags: c++, qt6

With Qt 6.3.0 `QVector` no longer has `fromStdVector` method.  I didn't fully understand the answers in [copying a std::vector to a qvector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129656/copying-a-stdvector-to-a-qvector) and would like to know how to modify the TreeWidgetController::getReponses method below.

In particular these templates were suggested:

```
std::vector<T> stdVec;
QVector<T> qVec = QVector<T>(stdVec.begin(), stdVec.end());
```

`foreach` is referenced [Qt foreach loop ordering vs. for loop for QList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825376/qt-foreach-loop-ordering-vs-for-loop-for-qlist) and here https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/foreach-keyword.html

The area I am unclear about is:
ResponsePtr could replace T but how would the `new ResponseItem` be handled?

```
// This is a sample of the code, I would like to upgrade
void TreeWidgetController::getResponses()
{
    // First remove all possible previous children.
    removeAllChildren(_rootResponses);
    // Retrieve the list of available responses.
    vector<ResponsePtr> responses = dbSubsystem().getResponses();
    // Create a new ResponseItem for every response.
    foreach (ResponsePtr r, QVector<ResponsePtr>::fromStdVector(responses))
        new ResponseItem(_rootResponses, r);
}
```

Comment: Do you even need the `QVector`? Seems like you could just iterate through `responses` and create a `ResponseItem`. `for (auto& r : responses) { new ResponseItem(_rootResponses, r);}`

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried what you have suggested. r is ResponsePtr, which is a a virtual DatabaseEntityPtr, and it seemed to work.  I built the component and visually everything looked good.  I am still debugging the application using Valgrind.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to re-invent the wheel here, just have a look at the `fromStdVector()` method that is in `qcorelib/tools/qvector.h` in earlier versions of Qt:

```
static inline QVector<T> fromStdVector(const std::vector<T> &vector)
{
   return QVector<T>(vector.begin(), vector.end());
}
```

You can either include that function verbatim in one of your own headers and leave your code unchanged, or use it as an example of how you can modify your code.